# End With without With. Not able to loop through columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So I'm trying to work on a single file, go to each cell in column A on "Source" (from row 1 to last row holding data), place that value in cell C3 on "Destination", recalculate the workbook and save the file

I haven't gotten to save the file yet because I am stuck on looping. Can anybody help please?

```
  Sub test()

            Sheets("Source").Select
            With ActiveSheet
            Set r = Range("Employee #")
            For n = 1 To r.Rows.Count
            r.Cells(n, 1).Select
            Selection.Copy

            End With

                Sheets("Destination").Select
                Range("C3").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next n


End Sub
```

Started VBA 7 days ago so I am trying to do my best here..

Comment: you can't end a with block that was started outside a loop inside that loop.  Wither end it before entering loop or end it after loop is over.

Comment: Why would you put all of the column A values from the source sheet into cell C3 on the destination sheet?

Comment: @ScottCraner, I initially tried doing that. It gave me a Runt-time error "1004". I appreciate your comment though.

Comment: @ExcelHero, I will save the file after replacing each of the cells into the destination sheet. It actually creates a report. For now i am just trying to make the loop work as I mentioned

Comment: I would learn early on not to use .select unless absolutely necessary.  You can refer to the ranges in question without selecting them directly.  It also appears like your code is generally pasting over cell C3 every time the loop runs.

Comment: @Yaegz,  I will take your point. For now i'm starting small and just getting things to run...
That is what i want to do for now. i will worry about saving each report later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In further review you do not need the with block

```
Sub test()

with Sheets("Source")
    Set r = .Range(.Range("A2"),.Range("A" &.row.count).end(xlup))'Change this to the column you want
end with
For n = 1 To r.Rows.count
    r.Cells(n, 1).copy Sheets("Destination").Range("C3")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next n


End Sub
```

or all the slects for that matter.  But now you can see that you are putting every value that you loop into one cell.

Comment: Thanks for the help Scott. It still gives me the runtime error "1004". Do you know what that means?

Comment: Tell me about the named range "Employee #", you should not be able to name it that.

Comment: Fair point. Its actually called "Br Code". But I replaced it when I ran the code

Comment: @NavySeal it is either that or you do not have sheets named "Source" or "Destination"

Comment: @NavySeal is "Br Code" a workbook name or a worksheet name.

Comment: Its a column name :/ - in sheet "source"

Comment: Excel does not have named columns.  Which column is it?  I assume you put "BR Code" In the first row of that column.